# MDX Query to include date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm using this query (MDX). It's returning data, but it's returning data for multiple years, where i'm trying to just get the dates in the date range: for example if I want 10/1/2013 the query returns 10/1/2013,10/1/2014,10/1/2015.
I'm looking for the specific date range, 10/13/2013 and 01/13/2014.
Why am I getting multiple years, where I specifically ask for that date range?

```
SELECT              {[Measures].[Network Calls Received]} 
                    ON COLUMNS,
                    non empty               

                   [Dim Time].[Half Hour of Day].members  ON Rows

FROM 

                  [OTS Analysis Services]
      where [Dim Date].[Date].&[10/13/2013]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[01/13/2014]
```

Comment: I'm looking for a mdx to return me that date, well really what in looking for is all Network calls received (one answer) where date range is the range above and time is 07:30 (19:30)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your filter has ONE wrong key. Once wrong key is used, server uses NULL instead of it.

Here is an example:

Unfiltered (to show data sample):
[image: SSAS_WrongKeys_Unfiltered]

Filtered correctly from March 2014 to June 2014:
[image: SSAS_WrongKeys_FilteredGood]

Than we add wrong key to the right member (and the same as using NULL!):
[image: SSAS_WrongKeys_FilteredBad_Right]

Once we use both wrong keys, no chance to figure out the dimension used (the same as both NULLs):
[image: SSAS_WrongKeys_FilteredBad_Both]

Please check both members, but especially [Dim Date].[Date].&[01/13/2014]. Looks like there is no such member in this dimension.

And keys addressing format needs checking too, as BI Dude wrote some time ago (many thanks to him!).

Comment: This answer is spot on - I've encountered the same - but not when using a range against dates as our date dimension is complete. When using the colon against a different dimension I also scratched my head for ages and then realised one side of the operator was being evaluated as Null.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your reference. Usually dimension member key is an integer.
so your range should look like

```
 where ([Dim Date].[Date].&[20131013]:[Dim Date].[Date].&[20140113])
```

You could check you member reference by:

1. Connecting to SSMS Analysis Services
2. Create New MDX Query.
3. Drag Date Member from The Hierarchy to the Editor.